# ionic cordova run android --prod hangs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

My ionic 3 project run OK with `ionic cordova run android`; however, if I added the `--prod` flag, i.e. `ionic cordova run android --prod`  The process hangs without any errors.  The following is where it stopped:

```
$ ionic cordova run android --prod
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
[23:16:47]  build prod started ...
[23:16:47]  clean started ...
[23:16:47]  clean finished in 8 ms
[23:16:47]  copy started ...
[23:16:47]  deeplinks started ...
[23:16:47]  deeplinks finished in 528 ms
[23:16:47]  ngc started ...
[23:17:01]  ngc finished in 13.21 s
[23:17:01]  preprocess started ...
[23:17:01]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[23:17:01]  webpack started ...
[23:17:01]  copy finished in 14.49 s
```

IT STOPPED HERE FOREVER...

I'd retried with many times with same result.  The following is my ionic info:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.11.2
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10
Environment Variables:
    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Android\android-sdk
Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Please help! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: Workaround for this is using
ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release

Try updating your ionic/app-scripts also

Reference # https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1426

Comment: Hello eduPeeth, I ran your command: ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release  and there was no stopping or errors. But how can I run this build with the connected device?  Please advice and thanks...

Comment: In other words, after the build using the command ionic cordova build android --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release.  Is there any command to run this build with the connected device like using the ionic cordova run android --prod command?  Please help. I'm   new to the ionic framework...Thanks...

Comment: Thanks eduPeeth, I got it. Using adb install -r /platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk and I'm able to launch the apk with the connected device.

Comment: Yes of course. But how to up vote your answer?  It seems that the screen only can accept answer.  Is it the same for up vote?

Comment: Please add the solution in the comments to the answer. Comments are intended to be temporary pieces of information and could possibly be deleted in the future.

Comment: This is likely due to the inclusion of Firebase. I used the 0.2.1 version of the @firebase/database and it will still build with --prod then

Answer (score 0):

Any one still having this issue, a big cause of this problem is PLUGINS

run `ionic cordova plugin`

And have a look at your list of plugins, and uninstall All the dodgy ones, and those you arent SURE are working by running `ionic cordova plugin rm your-plugin-name`

This is the problem 98% of the time.